# JSON Response with API.AI

Tags: ios, json, swift, webhooks, api-ai

I've been searching high and low on how to make use of `Webhook` in `API.AI`. I'm new to `API.AI` in general.

My objective is to integrate `API.AI` into my Swift Application which i have already done. I want to get a `JSON Object` from a webpage and use those data to manually add them as Entities/Intents/Response/etc by sending back a request to `API.AI`and then create them.

Tried posting on DialogFlow forums but i guess it's pretty inactive.

The whole workflow is..

1. Integrating `API.AI` into my Swift Application for users to use.
2. I have the base of the AI now.. `Intents` lead to `Entities` in a sense whereby users ask for a type of study, and an Entity `[Studies]` is triggered, so meaning from the `Intent` 'asking for a type of study' the response would be like Science, or something. This reply i want to get it from the `JSON` that i mentioned above, from a webpage. Is there any way to actually set these responses? Create entities etc, with my Swift Codes.

I hope it's clear enough.. And hope that anyone can point me in a direction as i can't seem to find any articles or somewhere to follow on it?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you describe step by step what you intend to do in your code?

Comment: Edited it! Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: I suggest you split your problem in two. Right now you are mixing iOS and a json response from a third party. Have you tried using postman? Then you can worry about parsing it...

Answer (score 0):

May be its late for answering this question, but few days back, I came across a similar situation. I countered it and wrote a tutorial series for the same. [Here's the link for tutorial.](https://medium.com/@pallavtrivedi03/building-a-chat-bot-having-ai-is-easy-2b52a4ce74fa) It might be useful for those who are looking to use API.AI, or want to integrate it in iOS project.

[Building a Chat Bot having AI is easy](https://medium.com/@pallavtrivedi03/building-a-chat-bot-having-ai-is-easy-2b52a4ce74fa)